# Reload captcha issues

Tags: javascript, php, captcha, reload

I am using this code: http://pastebin.com/Q9RXLZEd for my register page. I am trying to get the captcha to reload. The captcha code is a normal making image from PHP file code and the content type is a PNG image.

My current code doesn't have the captcha refresh or anything.

Another issue I thought of is, will the code for what the captcha answer is updated? If it doesn't, then doesn't that mean that the user will always get a captcha failure error if they use the refresh link?

Shiv

Comment: Make sure that `$_SESSION['string']` is updated by `image.php` when it generates a new captcha and it should work.

Comment: I can't do that because the content type is set to image on image.php

Comment: Doesn't matter what the content type is, if it's a php file you can set session variables inside it.

Comment: How would I update it then?

Comment: Somewhere in image.php you are generating a series of letters/numbers to be the captcha code (I'll assume the variable is called $captchaCode), and then creating an image from that.  You would simply do `$_SESSION['string'] = $captchaCode;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this within the `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 

 // refresh captcha
 $('img#captcha-refresh').click(function() {  

        change_captcha();
 });

 function change_captcha()
 {
    document.getElementById('captcha').src="captcha.php?rnd=" + Math.random();
 }

});


</script>
```

And this code wherever you want the captcha image and refresh icon (get a suitable refresh image and rename it to refresh.jpg) to appear. Remember this code and the code above (within the `<script>` tag) should be on the same page for the captcha to work.

```
<img src="captcha.php" alt="" id="captcha" />
Type the word:
 <input name="user_captcha" type="text" id="captcha-code">
 <img src="refresh.jpg"  alt="" id="captcha-refresh" />
```

Then create a file called captcha.php (it generates captcha image in png format, as requested).

```
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/png");

$word_1 = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) 
{
    $word_1 .= chr(rand(97, 122));
}

$_SESSION['random_number'] = $word_1;


$dir = "./";
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(165, 50);

$font = "whatever.ttf"; // font style you may give any you have / prefer

$color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);// color

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // background color white

imagefilledrectangle($image, 0,0, 709, 99, $white);

imagettftext ($image, 22, 0, 45, 30, $color, $dir.$font, $_SESSION['random_number']);

imagepng($image);  
?>
```

Then finally you have to check whether the user input and the text appearing in the captcha match or not by comparing `$_POST['user_captcha']` and `$_SESSION['random_number']` wherever you are passing the other values of the form.

N. B.: Do **NOT** forget to add session_start(); wherever you want the captcha image.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just add a random parameter to the URL of the PHP file generating the captcha (e.g. `image.php?param=randomvalue`). That way you can circumvent caching of the captcha image.

The code to reload the captcha could be something like this:

```
$("#refreshLink").click(function(){
    // Create some random string consisting of numbers
    var random = (Math.random() + "").substring(2);
    // Load a new captcha image by updating the image's src attribute
    $("#refresh img").attr("src", "image.php?param=" + random);
});
```

You'll also have to slightly adjust your HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Captcha:</td>
    <td><div id='refresh'><img src='image.php'></div></td>
    <td><a id='refreshLink'>Refresh</a></td>
</tr>
```

Regarding the second part of your question: As @James already said - if `image.php` sets `$_SESSION['string']` correctly every time the file is requested, users won't get captcha errors since the variable is only checked when the form is submitted. Session variables can be set regardless of the content type the PHP file actually returns in the end.